# Attach thermocouple to a PFC inductor

Tags: inductor, safety, temperature, thermocouple

The inductor I am talking about is simply a toroid. I am attaching a thermocouple junction to this component with help from thermal paste and aluminum tape.

Anything I should be careful about in this case? I think attaching TC to the wires might be okay, since they're all insulated by varnish. What about attaching it to the metal core? Would it cause problems?

On a side note, which type TC do you recommend for such application.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach it to the coil as you suggest, but try to run the wires along the surface for a bit since heat flow out the wires will affect the accuracy (and give you an optimistic value for the temperature rise). If there is a lot of dV/dT on the winding the readings may be erratic unless you  (say) ground one side of the thermocouple through a capacitor.

Better than a bead type sensor, you can buy glue-on polyimide-base thermocouples that are good for this application. Not too expensive, I recall about $100 for 5.

The alloy doesn’t much matter, types K and T are popular. Use what your instrumentation supports.

Comment: It is also very important to twist the TC wires if you are in a high dB/dt environment such as near the coil of a power inductor.

Comment: @tobalt I see. Can you explain why?

Comment: Induced voltage will thereby be minimized. The thermocouple will act as a single turn pickup coil so you want to minimize the effective loop area that sees the B field.

Comment: Also prefer plastic over metal tape.  Plastic is a bit insulating if anything, whereas metal may increase losses (due to the intense and uneven magnetic field very close to the wires) and the extra heat transfer may affect temperatures. Probably amounts to a few degrees difference, but just another uncertainty to avoid.